# FullCalendar parent height not working in flex layout

Tags: css, flexbox, fullcalendar

I've been working successfully with FullCalendar, but I'm having trouble with using the 'parent' height parameter when used within a flex layout. In the following code, the calendar does not seem to respect the height of the main section. It appears to be the height of the main section, plus the height of the footer. I've tried everything I can think of. I would appreciate any advice you may have. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>Calendar Test</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css" rel='stylesheet'/>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    header {
        height:75px;
    }

    main {
        flex: auto;
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    footer {
        height: 75px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>header</header>
<main id="calendar"></main>
<footer>footer</footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'month',
        height: 'parent',
        events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json'
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4650